# What kind of regex can allow special characters but refuse strings that only use special characters?

Tags: c#, regex

I am writing an regex for acceptable first names and last names.  Currently I only want to allow the following

- a to z
- A to Z
- '
- (-) (a dash symbol)
- diacritics

My regex is `@"^[a-zA-Z-'\p{L}]*$"`

Although I want to allow apostrophes and dashes, I also don't want the name to be *just* a dash, or *just* an apostrophe.  So to do this, I've written some extra regexes in Fluent Validator to catch these edge cases but it won't let me split them up.

```
        .Matches(@"^[a-zA-Z-'\p{L}]*$")
        .Matches(@"[^-]")
        .Matches(@"[^']");
```

This also isn't that great since I also don't want to allow names that are just apostrophes like '''''' or just dashes like ---------.

Is there a more effective regex that can be written to handle all of these cases?

Comment: Do you want to allow the empty string? (I'm assuming you don't). Also, mandatory reading: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: I assume you mean Combining Diatric marks `[\u0300-\u036f]` but I don't see it in your regex.

Comment: And an FYI, you can't parse out names with Regex, it's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
@"^(?![-']*$)[-'\p{L}]*$"
```

Also, `a-zA-Z` are included in `\p{L}`.

**Explanation:**

```
^          # Start of string
(?!        # Assert that it's impossible to match...
 [-']*     # a string of only dashes and apostrophes
 $         # that extends to the end of the entire string.
)          # End of lookahead.
[-'\p{L}]* # Match the allowed characters.
$          # End of string.
```

Comment: Nice. Probably `^\p{L}[-'\p{L}]*$` too behaves as desired.